# count total clicks made by user on entire site and change background accordingly

Tags: html, css, web

how would I go about tracking the number of click a user make on a site, and change the background accordingly, so for example: when a user lands of the first page the background is a small object, then as the user explores the site, the background changes, according to how many links have been clicked through, this would then cycle round.

these are the ideas i have come up with:

track the incoming source on each page, and if source was from this site, then add 1 to a counter stored in cookie, retrieve cookie and display corresponding background.

or to cause click on link to add one to counter in cookie.

any other suggestions or ideas? or is this bad practice or a very bad idea?

ps re research i tried and failed to find anything useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that easily with jQuery:

**EDIT with `$.cookie` usage:**

```
var totalClicks = ($.cookie('totalClicks' !== null) ? $.cookie('totalClicks') : 0;
var clicksLimit = 10;

$.cookie('clicksLimit', clicksLimit); // just so that you do not have to re-declare this variable on the other page.

$('body').on('click', '*', function() {
    totalClicks++;

    if(totalClicks >= clicksLimit) {
        alert('do something here...');

        // precise to your request:
        $('body').css('background-color', '#f00'); // will turn body background to "red"
    }

    $.cookie('totalClicks', totalClicks);
});
```

Comment: thank you, how could I make this persistent throughout the site, so when user moves from one page to the next, the click count is kept?

Comment: Then you can use jQuery's $.cookie()` plugin (download this plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). I will write a snipped of code how to use this example with cookies...

Comment: have you see this?

JavaScript is a dynamically-typed language commonly used for client-side scripting. Use this tag for questions regarding ECMAScript and its dialects/implementations (excluding ActionScript). Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected.

Comment: @ZlatanO. thanks for very fast excellent response, will be using a variant of this. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using simple javascript, using jQuery would increase load on the server:

```
var clicks = 0;
var limit = 10;

document.onclick = function() {
    if(clicks == 1) document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FFF";
    if(clicks == 2) document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#EEE";
    if(clicks == 3) document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#DDD";
    if(clicks == 4) document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#CCC";
    ....
    clicks++;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
// Get click amount from localStorage or use 0 if it doesn't exist
var clicks = localStorage['clicks'] || 0;

// Add the click className to the body first 
document.body.className = 'style-' + clicks;

// Set a eventListener 
document.addEventListener('click', function(){
   // clicks + 1
   clicks++;

   // Add new class name
   document.body.className = 'style-' + clicks;

}, false);


// When the window is about to be closed save the clicks in localStorage
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
   localStorage['clicks'] = clicks;
};
```

here is a fiddle ignore the buttons and just look at the body tag in dev tools

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4MTnM/2/)

you may have to do some cross browser work but it's the idea.

there is a polyfill for localStorage here https://gist.github.com/remy/350433

But--- if the browser doesn't support localStorage then this doesn't seem like a high priority feature for the site so the only thing that won't work it the state change on reload

Comment: If it's an older browser without `localStorage` support?

Comment: if they are using IE7 then they should probably get served print styles as far as I am concerned